# TikZ: Transitioning from snakes to decorations

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I'm trying to change a tikz-picture so it does not show a warning upon compilation.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[circle,draw] (S) at (0,0) {S};
\draw[snake=expanding waves,segment angle=25] (S)   -- (3,3);
%\draw[decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=25}] (S) -- (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, when I remove the snakes-code and uncomment the decoration-based code, i get an error saying

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrentname ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Now I checked both the examples from the manual as well as several related answers on this SE, none of which seemed to work for me.

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428051/tikz-snakes-expanding-waves-with-decorations), the only difference is that the decoration is used on a `\path` command instead of a `\draw`. I tried that, and it didn't work for me.
[Another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198443/tikz-setting-up-a-spring) suggests adding the correct sublibrary, which I would identify as `decorations.pathmorphing`, and trying this did not help either. 
Is there a general way (e.g. reading documentation) to tell which tikz-library or sublibrary has to be added to the document?

I find this problem rather frustrating, since the code that works for me without a visible downside (although I know that the snakes library is deprecated), and the supposedly optimal example code does not work at all. How can I solve this problem?

I noticed another similar question was closed for being too localized. If this should be the case for my question as well, how can I get help for this instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expanding waves are in the pathreplacing library, not pathmorphing, see page 581 of the documentation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (S) at (0,0) {S};
\draw[decoration={expanding waves,angle=25},decorate] (S) -- (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, I did not see that! Thank you for answering so fast!